# Selection from vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a long vector `data`. And a small vector `v` representing a set of indices related to the `data` vector. Now I want to make the following selection:

`data[v[1]:(v[1]+10)], data[v[2]:(v[2]+10)], ..., data[v[n]:(v[n]+10)]`

resulting in a 10-by-length (`v`) matrix.

My solution till now is:

```
d1 <- data[ v[1]:(v[1]+10)]
d2 <- data[ v[2]:(v[2]+10)]
d3 <- data[ v[3]:(v[3]+10)]
d4 <- data[ v[4]:(v[4]+10)]
d5 <- data[ v[5]:(v[5]+10)]
d6 <- data[ v[6]:(v[6]+10)]
d7 <- data[ v[7]:(v[7]+10)]
d8 <- data[ v[8]:(v[8]+10)]
d9 <- data[ v[9]:(v[9]+10)]
d0 <- data[v[10]:(v[10]+10)]
md <- matrix(c(d1,d2,d3,d4,d6,d7,d8,d9,d0),length(d1))
```

What would be a more R-style to do the job?

So that the code is not any more depending on the length of `v`.

Comment: Please do not use `<br/>` in your code. It makes it difficult to edit.

Comment: @Sven Actually you (and OP) probably mean `v[n] : (v[n] + 10)`. Otherwise it doesn’t really make sense (and is the same with and without parentheses anyway).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Right, this is the code I intended to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way with `embed`.

```
data <- 1:20
v <- c(3,5,7)
n <- 10
embed(data, max(v))[1:n,max(v)-v+1]
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, perhaps something like this would be of help:

```
m <- 1:20   ## Your "long" vector
v <- 1:5    ## Your "short" vector

## m[1:(1+5)], m[2:(2+5)], ... etc
sapply(v, function(x) m[x:(x+5)])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6
[3,]    3    4    5    6    7
[4,]    4    5    6    7    8
[5,]    5    6    7    8    9
[6,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

Comment: @BrodieG, :-) I'm not sure I've followed any of your last few comments. For me, the excuse is that it's almost midnight where I am. What's yours ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If your `n` is `10`, you will receive a matrix with `11` rows. Maybe you want indices of length `10` instead:

```
> data <- 1:20
> v <- c(3, 5, 7)
> n <- 10
> matrix(data[mapply(seq, v, v + n - 1)], n)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    3    5    7
 [2,]    4    6    8
 [3,]    5    7    9
 [4,]    6    8   10
 [5,]    7    9   11
 [6,]    8   10   12
 [7,]    9   11   13
 [8,]   10   12   14
 [9,]   11   13   15
[10,]   12   14   16
```